# Can I catch exceptions from async methods without await?

Tags: javascript, node.js, es6-promise

How can I catch exceptions from `doAsyncThing` without throwing an `await` in? Each run of `doAsyncThing` is idempotent so I just want all of the operations to happen "at the same time" & then wrap up the process. I realized even if I put a `try/catch` inside the `map`, it won't actually catch  it there because it's not in same thread at that point.

```
const promises  = entities.map(entity => {
  return entity.doAsyncThing();
});

await Promise.all(promises);
```

Comment: I think that the way Promise.all works is that you have to pass an array of the requests that you are going to do, Does entyty.doAsyncThing returns a request?. Check the docs [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all#Syntax)

Comment: @RicardoGonzalez - No, that is not correct.  `Promise.all()` takes an array of promises.  The promises get notified when the async operations complete.  The async operations have already started at the point you call `Promise.all()`.  There's no "array of requests" involved.

Comment: Does `doAsyncThing()` return a promise?  Can `doAsyncThing()` throw synchronously?  If one call to `doAsyncThing()` fails, what is it you want to do (given that the other calls to it are already running in parallel)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depends on what are you trying to achieve. Same as your code but without await would be

```
const promises  = entities.map(entity => {
  return entity.doAsyncThing();
});

Promise.all(promises).catch(e => {
  // handle exception
});
```

But you need to understand that it will catch if ANY of your promises reject and resolve if ALL of your promises resolve.

If  you want to handle every exception and get results of resolved promises you may need something like

```
const promises = entities.map(async entity => {
  try {
    return await entity.doAsyncThing();
  } catch (e) {
    // handle each exception
    return null;
  }
});

await Promise.all(promises);
```

Comment: It's funny to see the `.map` suggestion. I was thinking of this as well but wasn't sure this is an intended/guaranteed behavior. It  does work though.

Answer (score 6):

> Can I catch exceptions from async methods without await?

No, not with `try`/`catch`. At the time your `map` callbacks finish, your async tasks have not even completed yet. `promises` contains an array of *unsettled* promises (assuming `doAsyncThing` is actually doing async work and does not directly return a resolved or rejected promise).

Depending on what exactly you want to do, you have several options.

- Use `catch` within `map` to handle each thing individually:

```
const promises  = entities.map(entity => {
   return entity.doAsyncThing().catch(error => /* do something */);
});
await Promise.all(promises);
```

- Use `catch` on `Promise.all`:

```
const promises  = entities.map(entity => {
   return entity.doAsyncThing();
});
Promise.all(promises).catch(error => /* do something */);
```

- Use `try`/`catch`:

```
const promises  = entities.map(entity => {
   return entity.doAsyncThing();
});
try {
    await Promise.all(promises)
} catch (ex) {
    // do something
};
```