# Deno unexpected internal error encountered

Tags: ubuntu, server, fetch, deno

I make a lot of fetches through the fetch-API in Deno TypeScript. The problem now is that randomly I get the following error (can't be caught by try-catch):

```
error: Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: error sending request for url (https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/****@group.calendar.google.com/events/?calendarId=****group.calendar.google.com): http2 error: stream error received: unexpected internal error encountered
        const result: Response = await fetch(url, {
                                 ^
    at async mainFetch (deno:ext/fetch/26_fetch.js:288:14)
    at async fetch (deno:ext/fetch/26_fetch.js:505:9)
    at async gFetchEvent (file:///home/****/my_script.ts:98:27)
```

And I don't have any clue how to fix it. Is this a Deno bug?

I have the following deno version installed:

```
deno 1.25.2 (release, x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu)
v8 10.6.194.5
typescript 4.7.4
```

There is no particular line of code that breaks my program, just after some time (could be minutes, could be days) my program crashes with this error.

It only appears on my Ubuntu 20.04.5 LTS vServer by 1blu with the following hardware specs:

```
H/W path  Device       Class      Description
=============================================
                       system     Computer
/0                     bus        Motherboard
/0/0                   memory     8GiB System memory
/0/1                   processor  AMD EPYC 7452 32-Core Processor
/1        veth09bb0e5  network    Ethernet interface
/2        veth0ab53b0  network    Ethernet interface
/3        veth62387d0  network    Ethernet interface
/4        veth7dbc5b2  network    Ethernet interface
/5        vethb66edc6  network    Ethernet interface
```

(output of `sudo lshw -short`)

The code in my main script:

```
try {
  await main()
} catch (e) {
  console.log(new Date(), e.stack)
  Deno.writeTextFileSync(`logs/${Date.now()}`, "" + e.stack)
}
```

my main function

```
// this program checks changes in my school schedule and automatically puts them in my google calendar
export default async function main() {
  await Kantplaner.init()
  while (true) {
    // MKDate is just a class that extends Date for more functionallity, nothing special
    const start_day = new MKDate(Date.now())

    // repeats 14 times for the next 14 days
    for (let i = 0; i < 14; i++) {
      const date: MKDate = i ? start_day.nextDate(1) : start_day
      
      // get my schedule from my school's site
      const vplan: VPlan | null = await Indiware(date)
      if (!vplan) continue
      
      // fetch the existing events with google calendar api and check if something in the meantime changed
      const calendar = await Kantplaner.list_events(date)
      // male one big object containing all indices that were previously built by `await Indiware(date)`
      const GrandIndex = { ...vplan.data.KlassenIndex, ...vplan.data.LehrerIndex }
      for (const item of calendar.items) {
        const stundenNr = "some_string"
        const stundenMitDerID = GrandIndex[stundenNr]
        // if the event is not in my school's schedule anymore, delete it
        if (!stundenMitDerID) {
          await Kantplaner.delete_event(item.id)
          continue
        }
        // for every other event check differences and update the corresponding Google event
        // `stundenMitDerID` is an array of events with the same id (can happen at my school)
        for (let i = 0; i < stundenMitDerID.length; ++i) {
          // ... create update (doesn't matter)
          const update: Kantplaner.Update = {}
          await Kantplaner.update_event(item.id, update)
          // remove lesson from index to avoid another creation
          GrandIndex[stundenNr].splice(i)
          if (GrandIndex[stundenNr].length == 0) delete GrandIndex[stundenNr]
        }
      }
      // create every remainig event
      for (const stundenNr in GrandIndex) {
        const stundenMitDerID = GrandIndex[stundenNr]
        for (let i = 0; i < stundenMitDerID.length; ++i) {
          await Kantplaner.create_event({
            // event data
          })
        }
      }
    }
    // wait one minute to reduce unnecessary fetches
    await new Promise(r => setTimeout(r, 60_000))
  }
}
```

All appearances of `gFetchEvent`:

```
export async function list_events(date: MKDate, TIME_SHIFT: string): Promise<Calendar> {
    const calendar: Calendar | null = await gFetchEvent("/", "GET", {
        timeMin: date.format(`yyyy-MM-ddT00:00:00${TIME_SHIFT}`),
        timeMax: date.format(`yyyy-MM-ddT23:59:59${TIME_SHIFT}`),
    })
    if (!calendar) return EMPTY_CALENDAR

    let nextPageToken = calendar.nextPageToken
    while (nextPageToken) {
        const nextPage: Calendar = await gFetchEvent("/", "GET", {
            pageToken: nextPageToken,
            timeMin: date.format(`yyyy-MM-ddT00:00:00${TIME_SHIFT}`),
            timeMax: date.format(`yyyy-MM-ddT23:59:59${TIME_SHIFT}`),
        })
        calendar.items.push(...nextPage.items)
        nextPageToken = nextPage.nextPageToken
    }
    return calendar
}

export async function create_event(event: Event) {
    await gFetchEvent("/", "POST", { calendarId: CALENDAR_ID }, event)
}

export async function update_event(eventId: string, update: Update) {
    await gFetchEvent(`/${eventId}`, "PATCH", {
        sendUpdates: "none"
    }, update)
}

export async function delete_event(eventId: string) {
    await gFetchEvent(`/${eventId}`, "DELETE", {
        calendarId: CALENDAR_ID,
        eventId: eventId,
        sendUpdates: "none"
    })
}
```

The code where I fetch:

```
async function gFetchEvent(urlPath: string, method: string, params?: { [key: string]: string }, body?: any) {
    if (!initiated) return null
    const url = new URL(CALENDAR_API_URL + urlPath)
    if (params) for (const key of Object.keys(params)) url.searchParams.append(key, params[key])

    const result: Response = await fetch(url, {
        headers: {
            Authorization: "Bearer " + access_token,
            Accept: "application/json",
            "Content-Type": "application/json"
        },
        method: method,
        body: JSON.stringify(body)
    })
    
    await new Promise(f => setTimeout(f, 100))
    if (result.ok) {
        const text = await result.text()
        if (text.length > 1) return JSON.parse(text)
        else return {}
    } else if (result.status == 403) {
        gFetchEvent(urlPath, method, params, body)
        return
    }
    return null
}
```

Every function call like `list_events` or `update_event` implicitly calls `gFetchEvent` function (with the different url's and ).

Comment: Have you tried on the latest version? and please show your `fetch` call, anyhow if it can't be caught, it's a bug on Deno.

Comment: although I'm certain you might not be catching the error correctly, can you post your code please? Including your error handler

Comment: Yes. After the update I tried it again and around ninety minutes later it crashed. Let me just update the question with my code.

Comment: Please show main function.

Comment: You're missing the part where you call fetch, and the error handler. GFetchEvent

Comment: If you don't add the code where `gFetchEvent`is called, it's impossible to see whether you're handling the error correctly. It'll be easier if you post full code or share a link at least.

Comment: No I'm not. The error handler is in the main script: ```try {
  await main()
} catch (e) {
  console.log(new Date(), e.stack)
  Deno.writeTextFileSync(`logs/${Date.now()}`, "" + e.stack)
}```
And the fetch call is the last code block

Comment: Are you calling `gFetchEvent` without `await` in any place in your code?

Comment: Oh, yes I did, but totally forgot about that line. Sorry about that.

Comment: Can you show it?

Comment: I guess that's also where the type error came from. I did not return null or an empty object but nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing an `await`, without it, the error won't bubble correctly to the `try/catch` in your `main` function.

```js
    if (result.ok) {
        const text = await result.text()
        if (text.length > 1) return JSON.parse(text)
        else return {}
    } else if (result.status == 403) {
        // You were missing an await here
        const res = await gFetchEvent(urlPath, method, params, body)
        return res;
        // or just
        // return gFetchEvent(urlPath, method, params, body);
    }
```

---

Alternatively if you don't want to use `await` in that path, you can attach a `.catch` handler to `gFetchEvent` to prevent the `Uncaught Promise` error.

- [Why is try {} .. catch() not working with async/await function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68102365/why-is-try-catch-not-working-with-async-await-function)
- [Can I catch exceptions from async methods without await?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58223219/can-i-catch-exceptions-from-async-methods-without-await)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Marcos Casagrande I realized that I had a call to an async function that throws an error without an await. That would not be a problem if there was no error thrown by the fetch.

But some error by fetch (most likely a network error) caused exactly this error to be thrown.

Comment: No, the uncaught TyperError in your question was due to the missing await. Not due to the undefined returned.

Comment: Why should there be a TypeError because I forgot to await an async function?

Comment: The TyperError in the message is fetch failing. The Uncaught Promise part of the error is due to missing await to properly propagate the error.

Comment: Thanks. But why does fetch fail?

Comment: Network error most likely.